# Windows 10 Store app deployment failed, Invalid URI

Tags: deployment, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal, monogame

**DEP0600: Deployment failed. UriFormatException - Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. [0x80131537]**

I have a MonoGame UWP app, that will not deploy to the local machine for debugging. I can however, deploy to a remote machine.

**Update:**
I pulled my repository into a new, duplicate folder. This, I was able to successfully deploy and run. This means there is some sort of build related file/s that can cause this.

I need to know what this is, because this will happen again.

Comment: Could you please share your git url? So that we can try to reproduce this exception.

Comment: I can't do that. I'm working on a closed source project, based in Mercurial.

Is there anything else I could provide?

Comment: If the issue is related to the current project as your update indicates then there isn't much we can do without accessing  your project - perhaps you could remove delicate information so that you have a 'barebones' app, and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Same "fix" for me. Deleted my local folder and pulled a fresh copy of the repo. Deployed just fine.

Comment: I get this issue when deploying from a network drive.